# given the html content, find out the height of the page for the given width,before rending the page

Tags: html, xhtml

i am interested in finding out the height for a given width,taken by the webpage for the given HTML content.
Ex.say given html content is,

> < html> < body> < h6>My First Heading<
>   /h6> < p>My first paragraph.... ...
>   ....< /p> < /body> < /html>

========================================

How can i find out the height the webpage(corresponding to the given content), for a given width ?
i  want to calculate the height before loading the webpage... i.e i dont render the page, but using the "contents" only,i want to calculate the height...

Comment: you have to atleast use some browser layout engine.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done unless there are attributes or CSS rules that define their width or height. By themselves, HTML elements have no inherent dimensions, and therefore you cannot measure them.